# Placing widget on to the window (Using tkinter)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create the interface for my program using tkinter library.

My interface should appears like this

BUTTON1

BUTTON2

BUTTON3

```
B.pack(side = "left", padx = 00, pady = 0)
C.pack(side = "left", padx = 100, pady = 100)
D.pack(side = "left", padx = 50, pady = 120)
```

I have already tried to change the parameters for padx and pady, 
But still it appears in the same line. I am using ubuntu 13.04 OS

How to set the parameters to get the desired format

Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem in three simple steps.  First, remove all of the `padx`'s because they throw the buttons out of alignment.  Second, use `anchor = "w"` to make the buttons left justified.  Third, set `side` equal to `"top"` so that the buttons are placed vertically and not horizontally.  (however, since `side` defaults to "top", you can just remove it altogether).  Below is the fixed script:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button

root = Tk()

B = Button(root, text="BUTTON1")
C = Button(root, text="BUTTON2")
D = Button(root, text="BUTTON3")

B.pack(anchor = "w", pady = 0)
C.pack(anchor = "w", pady = 100)
D.pack(anchor = "w", pady = 120)

root.mainloop()
```

Another alternative is to use the `grid` method instead of `pack`:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, W

root = Tk()

B = Button(root, text="BUTTON1")
C = Button(root, text="BUTTON2")
D = Button(root, text="BUTTON3")

# 'row' sets the row number that the widget is placed on
# 'sticky' is the same as 'anchor'
B.grid(row=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
C.grid(row=1, pady=100, sticky=W)
D.grid(row=2, pady=120, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

While I personally prefer `grid` over `pack`, the decision is really just a matter of preference.

Comment: I think your answer would be better if you mentioned that simply removing `side=left` isn't precisely why your solution works. Rather, the default for `side` is `"top"`, so either explicitly setting it to `"top"` or accepting the default is why your solution works.

Comment: If you recommend using grid, you should also recommend using `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` so that the GUI has proper resize behavior.

Comment: Finally, I disagree that grid gives "far greater control". It's not greater, just different. For placing buttons in a stack or row, pack is arguably superior. grid, of course, is superior for putting things in a grid. And as for greatest "control", place lets you specify precisely where a widget goes. I think it's bad advice to suggest only using pack for "quick and simple GUIs". I've created many complex, commercial GUIs and I use pack a lot. The right advice is to learn them all and use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I guess you are right.  I just prefer `grid` over `pack` and have used it since I began making GUI's.  `pack` routinely fails me where `grid` succeeds (I don't know, maybe I'm not using it right).  Thus, I try to steer people off of it.  However, after reading your comments, I can kinda see that my stuff concerning `grid` was really just opinion based, so I have edited my post.  Thanks for taking the time and care to help me improve the quality of my answer.

Comment: @iCodez I have tried by changing the coordinates, but to my surprise, when I tried by specifying the second and third button pady coordinates same, but both placed in different position

Comment: @iCodez how is that possible ??

Comment: @Raj - `pady` doesn't set the coordinates of the widget but rather how much padding (surrounding space) to give the widget vertically.